# How to set precedence of condition in MYSQL when two conditions are given using OR?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
  $sqlquery1 = "SELECT * 
                FROM item 
                WHERE item.title LIKE '%abc%' 
                   OR item.idescription LIKE '%abc%'";
```

and this is running perfectly.

The only concern is that I want to show the results of the first OR condition (item.title) at first preceded by the next condition.

> Eg of current output:

Title: ALGEBRA 
Description: **abc** inc

Title: **ABC** 
Description: dsdsinc

Title: Al**ABC**ad 
Description: sds inc

> Eg of Desired output:

Title: **ABC** 
Description: dsdsinc

Title: Al**ABC**ad 
Description: sds inc

Title: ALGEBRA 
Description: **abc** inc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the other answers, you may want to rank items where the term occurs in both the `title` and `description` higher then just the ones with term just in the `title`.

```
SELECT * , title_score + description_score AS total_score
FROM (
    SELECT * , title LIKE '%abc%' AS title_score, description LIKE '%abc%' AS description_score
    FROM item
    WHERE title LIKE '%abc%'
OR description LIKE '%abc%'
) AS temp_tbl
ORDER BY total_score DESC, title_score DESC, description_score DESC
```

In addition to these answers you can use a `FULLTEXT` index with a `score` result which will rank your search based on the number of times the term is found.

```
SELECT * , MATCH(title, description) AGAINST ('*abc*') AS score
    FROM item
    WHERE MATCH(title, description) AGAINST ('*abc*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ORDER BY score DESC
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want rows returned in a specific order, add an `ORDER BY` clause.

To meet the stated specification, this  would be sufficient:

```
 ORDER BY item.title LIKE '%abc%' DESC
```

This works, because MySQL evaluates a boolean expression and returns the result as integer: TRUE is returned as 1, FALSE is returned as 0 and NULL or unknown is returned as NULL.  We can demonstrate this with a simple test, e.g.

```
SELECT 'abc' LIKE '%abc%'
     , 'foo' LIKE '%abc%'
     ,  NULL LIKE '%abc%'
```

And see that MySQL returns 1, 0 and NULL respectively.

Personally, I would prefer more expressions in the `ORDER BY` to make the result more deterministic, so that the rows are guaranteed to be returned in a predictable and repeatable order.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a value to each match condition and order by that. When you do this, it's good to have a "tie-breaker" order so you don't get all the title matches randomly ordered followed by all of the description matches randomly ordered:

```
SELECT *
FROM item
WHERE item.title LIKE '%abc%' OR item.idescription LIKE '%abc%'
ORDER BY
  CASE(WHEN item.title like '%abc%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  item.title,
  item.description;
```

This is similar to spencer7593's solution except it can be expanded to handle more than two "OR" conditions if needed.